# How to isolate a tuple from sql ordering while ordering the rest?

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched for an answer here and didn't find one closer to my question.

I have the following situation: I need to display a person first and then show the rest in ascending order. All the people from the same table. I tried UNION but after that, the SQL seems to mix everything again.

I have tried this:

```
select name from people where name = 'John'
UNION
select name from people order by name
```

Since UNION does not select duplicated values. But in the end, it mixed up every result and did not show in the correct order that should be:

```
John
Ana
Bruce
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `order by` to get what you want.  In MySQL, this is pretty easy:

```
select name
from people
order by (name = 'John') desc, name
```

Results sets (like tables) represent *unordered* sets in SQL.  The only way to impose an order is to use `order by`.  The `order by` at the end of a `union`/`union all` query applies to the entire query.

As an aside, your code would come close to working if you used `union all` -- which is much preferred over `union`.  The `union` operation does additional work to remove duplicates.  In this case, that reorders the results, a convenient reminder that you can only depend on the order of results when you use `order by`.

Comment: To clarify a little: @bpinhosilva's query did contain an `order by` but only on part of the query. The result of the `union` was not ordered.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, that worked good!
But it arose another question, I put UNION ALL, parentheses over the second query and exclude John from the second query and I still get the same mixed up result. Is there a way to use UNION so that it just concatenates the result without reordering?

Comment: Thanks, @dave, you clarified a little more about the order by I put above.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the clarification. That's a great analysis and I learned something.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use `UNION ALL` in a derived table

```
SELECT name
FROM 
(
    SELECT 1 AS Row_Id, name
    FROM people
    WHERE name = 'John'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 2 AS Row_Id, name
    FROM people
) t
ORDER BY Row_Id
```